# Add selected records as a rowexpander data into available grid

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I have a grid panel which is employee can select articles from the system. Also, there are two fields and employee must fill those fields as well. When an employee click the button ADD ( in this case EKLE ) the selected records should add background grid with this two field value ( LEVEL and VALUE fields). The system works properly without field values. I want to add those fields value by `rowexpander` plugin into background grid.

[image]

**Buttons Code**

```
{
text: 'EKLE',
scale: 'medium',
disabled: true,
width: 100,
margin: '0 9 0 0',
cls: 'btn-article-save',
id: 'btnArticleSave',
name: '_btnArticle',
listeners: {
    click: function () {
        var sel = Ext.getCmp('article-grid').getSelectionModel().getSelection();
        Ext.each(sel, function (item, index) {
            arrArticle.push(item);
        });

        arrArticleStore.load();
        Ext.getCmp('articles-grid').getView().bindStore(arrArticleStore);
        Ext.getCmp('articles-grid').show();

        var alevel = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=artLevel]');
        var avalue = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('textfield[name=artValue]');
    }
}
}
```

**Background Grid Code**

```
{
xtype: 'gridpanel',
id: 'articles-grid',
selType: 'rowmodel',
store: arrArticleStore,
elStatus: true,
hidden: true,
columnLines: true,
forceFit: true,
scroll: 'vertical',
width: 730,
height: 394,
columns: [
    {text: 'ARTICLE ID', dataIndex: 'ARTICLE_ID', hidden: true},
    {text: 'ARTİKEL TANIMI', dataIndex: 'ART_DESC', width: 210, flex: 2},
    {
        text: 'VARIANT TANIMI',
        dataIndex: 'SORTEN_TEXT',
        width: 120,
        flex: 1,
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            if (value == null) {
                return record.get('ART_DESC');
            } else {
                return record.get('SORTEN_TEXT');
            }
        }
    },
    {text: 'VARIANT', dataIndex: 'VAR', width: 72, align: 'center', flex: 0},
    {text: 'GEBI', dataIndex: 'GEBI', width: 72, align: 'center', flex: 0},
    {text: 'SUBSYS', dataIndex: 'SUBSYS_ART_NR', width: 72, align: 'right', flex: 0},
    {
        text: 'DNR ID',
        dataIndex: 'DNR_ID',
        width: 80,
        align: 'center',
        flex: 0,
        renderer: function (value, metaData, record) {
            if (value == 0) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return record.get('DNR_ID');
            }
        }
    },
    {text: 'STATUS', dataIndex: 'STATUS', hidden: true},
    {
        text: 'SİL',
        align: 'center',
        xtype: 'actioncolumn',
        width: 60,
        flex: 0,
        items: [
            {
                icon: '<?php echo img_url(); ?>delete.png',
                tooltip: 'DNR Bilgilerini Görüntüle',
            }
        ]
    }
],
style: {
    fontFamily: 'DINPro-Regular',
    fontSize: '10pt',
    marginBottom: '10px'
},
multiSelect: true,
viewConfig: {
    getRowClass: function (record) {
        if (record && record.get('STATUS') === 1) return 'article-available-row';
    }
}
}
```